# Position and opening of my sub sub-menu is wrong

Tags: html, css, menu, position, submenu

I am trying to create a website and I need a multi level submenu. 
I am facing 2 problems at the moment:

1. I dont know how to position the sub sub menu properly. It should appear next to the sub menu on the same height as the previous menu item and list downwards.
2. I don't know how to set that the sub sub menu only expands if I hover the corresponding sub menu item. 
   The code I am using is attached below.

I would appreciate if only the css is changed because the website runs with a programme that creates the html
The code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/Luxrakzq/

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #ccc;
            color: #00782E;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        
        /* Header Leiste */
        .nav{
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background: #00782E;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 2;
        }

    /* Hintergrund für Obermenüpunkte */
    .nav ul {
        width: 60%;
        height: 70px;
        list-style: none;
        background: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-right: 15%;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    /* Position Menüoberpunkte */
    .nav li {
        line-height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    /* Style Menüoberpunkte */
    .nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .menulist {
        display: none;
    }
    
    dropdown-content ul {
        display: none;
    }
    
    
    /*  Untermenü bei Hovern anzeigen*/
    .dropdown:hover .menulist.menulist{
        display: block;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background: white;
    }
    
    .menulist .menulist {
        background-color: red !important;
        width: 280px !important;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content ul ul {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .menulist ul:hover .dropdown-content ul ul {
        display: block !important;
    }
    
    /* Untermenüpunkte erster Ordnung Style*/
    .menulist a {
        color: #00782E;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 150px;
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .menulist .menulist a {
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-top: 6px,
        padding-bottom: 6px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 6px;
    }
    
    /* Abstand Untermenütext 1 zum Kasten */
    .menulevel1 {
        margin-left: 6px;
    }
    
    /* Untermenüpunkte 2. Ordnung Style */
    .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #00782E;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 150px;
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        color: lightgrey !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class ="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="animals" class="dropbtn">Animals</a>
                    <div class = "dropdown-content">
                        <ul class="menulist">
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="lion">Lion</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="cat">cat</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="monkey">monkey</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="cow">cow</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="sheep">sheep</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="rat">rat</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="names" class="dropbtn">names</a>
                    <div class = "dropdown-content">
                        <ul class="menulist">
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="Pete">Pete</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="Finley">Finley</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="#">Jordan <span class="Jordan"></span></a>
                                <ul class="menulist">
                                    <li class="menulevel2">
                                        <a class=" " href="calvin">Calvin</a>
                                        <li class="menulevel2">
                                            <a class=" " href="harry">harry</a>
                                        </li>
                                        
                                        </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menulevel1">
                                <a class=" " href="george">george</a>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </body>
    
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using the basic bootstrap (other comparable) framwork and customize it from there?

Comment: Because you are setting display block at submenu ul when you hover the top-level menu link `.dropdown`. You should do `.menulevel1:hover .menulist { display: block; }` and `.menulist` needs to be `display: none` by default.

Comment: I am not using an existing method because the website is based on an organisation tool. The tool has many tools integrated that are essential for my website. The only way to embed the tools in the website properly is to use a placeholder that generates the HTML for the menu.